# How to toggle mobile menu after click?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu

In my client's website, the navigation links are used for anchor scrolling and also for internal pages. When I click a link for an internal page, obviously the menu disappears once the new page is loaded. However, when I click a link for an anchor, it scrolls to the desired page section, but the menu won't toggle. It's confusing because it seems like nothing happened and the user can't see the content because the menu is hiding it.

How can I toggle the mobile menu after clicking a link for an anchor?

I've tried this approach, but nothing happened:

```
 <script>
  $('#menu-mobile-open a').click(function (e) {
    $('#menu-mobile-open').collapse('toggle');
  });
</script>
```

The website is: [www.amgeventoss.com.br](http://www.amgeventoss.com.br)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have just gone through you site and found this solution is working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.menu-mobile .menu-link').on('click',function() {
        jQuery('#menu-mobile-close').click();
   });
});
```

just add this to your js and it should work like charm

Comment: Hello, @NiravAdatiya! Just added the code to core/scripts/core.js and it worked. Thank you very much!